# translate mongodb aggregation query to spring-data-mongodb

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

is it possible to translate this mongo shell aggregation query to spring-data?

```
db.getCollection("X").aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                year: {
                    $year: "$happenedAt"
                },
                month: {
                    $month: "$happenedAt"
                },
                day: {
                    $dayOfMonth: "$happenedAt"
                }
            },
            count: {
                $sum: 1
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
Criteria c=new Criteria(Criteria.where("year").is(y).and("month").is(m).and("day").is(d));
Aggregration a=newAggregration(match(c),group("year","month","day").count().as("total"));
```

That is it.